# how to use mysql function "min()" with two criteria in one query

Tags: mysql, min

I have a table of items some are second hand and some are new,

I would like a query giving me the minimum price for the new version of the item as well as the second hand version.

I have a boolean field called "new" who tell if the item is second hand or not

for the result I have to do two query but I think its possible to do only one

query for the second hand :

```
SELECT  ref_product, MIN( price ) 
FROM item_list
WHERE new = 0
GROUP BY ref_produit
```

query for the new :

```
SELECT  ref_product, MIN( price ) 
FROM item_list
WHERE new = 1
GROUP BY ref_produit
```

I would like that kind of result :

> ref_product | min_price_for _secondhand | min_price_for_new

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  ref_product, 
        MIN(case when new = 1 then price else null end) as new_price,
        MIN(case when new = 0 then price else null end) as used_price
FROM item_list
GROUP BY ref_product
```

Comment: Nice, this one gets a single row for each product, containing the min price for both new and second hand versions of the product. It gets `NULL` for `new_price` or `used_price` when the product is not available as new or SH.

Comment: `MIN(IF(new = 1, price, NULL))` is shorter and more readable, I think.

Comment: thanks man you are my god its exactly what I wanted, merry christmas

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT ref_product, MIN( price ) 
FROM item_list 
WHERE new in (0,1)
GROUP BY new, ref_product
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the condition on `new` (get all products) and group by `ref_produit' then by`new`:

```
SELECT ref_product, new, MIN(price) AS min_price
FROM item_list
GROUP BY ref_produit, new
```

Comment: This query gets distinct rows for new and used products, if available. They can be detected by checking the value of the column `new`.

Comment: Nice one its not what I wanted but at least I have the information I need in only one query, thanks